# Is there a command to make Ubuntu's boot menu look like Fedora's?

Tags: boot, grub2

Basically to show all available kernel versions in the main menu, without the need to drill down to the Advanced Options.

Answer (score 0):

The Grub display is generated via `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Read that file, look at the files in `/etc/grub.d`, which are used to generate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, read `man -k grub`, but....

**BEWARE** If you change `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (or the way it is produced) you could end up with a Non-Booting system, aka Doorstop.